# How to ignore null values in Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator

I have a comparator that compares nested fields of an object. Here the `price` of a `product`.

Problem: if the field is null, I'm getting a NullPointerException.

Question: how can I tell the comparator to ignore objects where the comparing field is null, without(!) having to filter the list beforehand? With ignore I mean having them at the end of the list.

```
public class SorterTest {
    private static final Comparator<Product> PRODUCT_COMPARATOR = 
           Comparator.comparing(p -> p.details.price);

    static class Product {
        String name;
        Details details;

        static class Details {
            BigDecimal price;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(
                createProduct("A", new BigDecimal(30.00)),
                createProduct("B", new BigDecimal(55.00)),
                createProduct("C", new BigDecimal(20.00)),
                createProduct("D", null),
                createProduct("E", null),
                createProduct("F", null)
        );

        Collections.sort(products, PRODUCT_COMPARATOR);
        assertEquals("C", products.get(0).name);
        assertEquals("A", products.get(1).name);
        assertEquals("B", products.get(2).name);
        assertEquals("D", products.get(3).name);
        assertEquals("E", products.get(4).name);
        assertEquals("F", products.get(5).name);
    }

    private Product createProduct(String name, BigDecimal price) {
        Product p = new Product();
        p.details = new Product.Details();
        p.name = name;
        p.details.price = price;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
    at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:221)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1438)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.sort(Arrays.java:3895)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
```

Comment: [`Comparator.nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) ?

Comment: You have to decide is `null` greater or less than other values and write code which reflects that.

Comment: `null` should be less then all other values. How can I teach the comparator?

Comment: What do you mean, "ignore"? You're currently sorting a list of elements. What happens with the elements that are "ignored"?

Comment: Updated my question. ignore means just put them at the end of the list (as seen in the expected values in my unit test).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the method nullsLast of the Comparator:

```
   private static final Comparator PRODUCT_COMPARATOR = 
           Comparator
           .nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.details.price, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

The first nullsLast for Product being null, the second for price being null.

Comment: This looks promising, but causes the same exception!

Comment: @membersound Because NPE is this case is not thrown from Comparator, but from `p -> p.details.price` lambda invocation.
This should work:

`private static final Comparator PRODUCT_COMPARATOR = 
Comparator.comparing(p -> Optional.ofNullable(p.details).map(Product::getPrice).orElse(null),
 Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));`

Answer (score 0):

You get the NullPointerException because of the price is null. So use an if statement to check the price value, and if is null then use other value like 0 to replace it. The code may like:

```
public class SorterTest {
    private static final Comparator<Product> PRODUCT_COMPARATOR =
            Comparator.comparing(p->
                    {
                        if (p.details != null && p.details.price != null) {
                            return p.details.price;
                        } else {
                            return new BigDecimal(0);
                        }
                    }
            );

    static class Product {
        String name;
        Details details;

        static class Details {
            BigDecimal price;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(
                createProduct("A", new BigDecimal(30.00)),
                createProduct("B", new BigDecimal(55.00)),
                createProduct("C", new BigDecimal(20.00)),
                createProduct("D", null),
                createProduct("E", null),
                createProduct("F", null)
        );

        Collections.sort(products, PRODUCT_COMPARATOR);
        assertEquals("D", products.get(0).name);
        assertEquals("E", products.get(1).name);
        assertEquals("F", products.get(2).name);
        assertEquals("C", products.get(3).name);
        assertEquals("A", products.get(4).name);
        assertEquals("B", products.get(5).name);
    }

    private Product createProduct(String name, BigDecimal price) {
        Product p = new Product();
        p.details = new Product.Details();
        p.name = name;
        p.details.price = price;
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include an explanation of what you've changed in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Optional<> to see if the result from getter is a null or a valid value. For null values, you can put them at the tail or head by always treating their comparator() result is -1 or 1.

```
private static final Comparator<Product> PRODUCT_COMPARATOR = 
           Comparator.comparing(p -> {
               Optional<BigDecimal> res = Optional.ofNullable(p.getPrice);
               if(res.isPresent())
                   return p.getPrice();
               else
                   return -1;
           });
           ...
static class Product {
        String name;
        BigDecimal price;

        BigDecimal getPrice(){
            return this.price;
        }
        ...
}
```